# Raspberry pi Minecraft server

Tags: raspberry-pi, minecraft

I am trying to host a Minecraft server for my friends with my raspberry pi. However, I cannot connect to it out of my network. I am connecting to it via Ethernenet. I have also tried connecting via the default spigot port (ip address:Port). When trying, it just says cannot connect to server. Any help is appreciated
Pi- 4B+
Connection- usb 3.0 Ethernet on Eth1
Server- spigot
Version- 1.8.9
Os- raspberry pi full 64 bit

Comment: Have you created a Port Forward in your router?

Comment: If not, take a read of https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/how-to-host-and-configure-a-minecraft-server-with-no-ip/

Comment: Ok I will try that